Trying to run old Nest JS project leads to dependencies conflict
Good day.
I'm trying to "reanimate" an old studding project written in Nest, but when I try to launch the project it gives errors due to conflicts in dependencies (some of them are deprecated), I tried to solve the problem by deleting the node modules folder and the json lock file, and then to update their dependencies again, but new conflicts arise between them leading to more errors.
Here is link to the repository:
https://github.com/YouNone/nest-admin-backend

It is very unlikely that someone will take the time to clone your project on their machine and find out exactly what dependency errors you are talking about. Include those details in your question instead, github is an addition, not a primary source of information on Stackoverflow. I would advise you to find out what version of Node your application was once running on, and which exact versions of libs from package.json were installed. And also figure out what does "^" in the package.json means and think about how you can restore working versions of packages using the package-lock.json file
